# Dualboot Win7&Kubuntu 15.04 (Win7 is lost in Bootmenu)

Tags: dual-boot

i installed first Win7 Ultimate (without EFI) and then Kubuntu 15.04.
I choose the first and second Partition as Win7, the Kubuntu ones as root,home,var,exchange,swap
In my Dolphin manager I See both win7 partitionen. 
But i Cant start with win7 ... I Try a little bit in the bootmenu but no sucess.

When you know how to solve the Problem.... optional how can i choose at the start?
The main workingvSystem for me is kubuntu, but for some games it would be nice with an win7.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a GRUB program install ? if you have this, the program tell you if you want put Windows or kubuntu or other operating system what you have!